# these two lines of codes, crash my app, when I change app theme but I need them, what should I do? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I tried different ways untill I figured out that the problem is with the bellow these textViews:

```
name.text = user.name+" "+user.lastName
            phoneNumber.text = user.phoneNumber
```

I used them into a Datasnapshot to retrive {user name and last name and phone number} data on navigationdrawer header like bellow:

```
private fun getUserData() {
    val scoresRef = Firebase.database.getReference("Users")
    scoresRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)!!
            val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvFirstNameAndLastName)
            val phoneNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPhoneNumber)
            name.text = user.name+" "+user.lastName
            phoneNumber.text = user.phoneNumber
            getUserProfile()
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            finish()
        }
    })
}
```

when I remove that two lines, everything works fine and no problem with theme and changing language, but by using them data fetching is OK and no problem too, I just want to change app theme or language but this error shows in logcat after app crashed :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at af.azdreams.myconquer.DashboardActivity$getUserData$1.onDataChange(DashboardActivity.kt:293)
```

1- this is my activity_dashboard.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DashboardActivity">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Orange"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSearchUsers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_search"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/menu"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2- this is the DashboardActivity.kt :

```
import af.azdreams.myconquer.databinding.ActivityDashboardBinding
import af.azdreams.myconquer.fragments.ExploreFragment
import af.azdreams.myconquer.fragments.FlightsFragment
import af.azdreams.myconquer.fragments.TravelFragment
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import java.io.File
import java.util.*

class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference
private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var user: User
private lateinit var uid: String
private var toolbar: Toolbar? = null
private var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
private var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
private var exploreFragment: ExploreFragment? = null
private var flightsFragment: FlightsFragment? = null
private var travelFragment: TravelFragment? = null
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var binding: ActivityDashboardBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    uid = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    if (uid.isNotEmpty()){
        getUserData()
    }
    loadLocale()
    binding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    onClickListenerSearchUser()
    val scoresRef = Firebase.database.getReference("Users")
    scoresRef.keepSynced(true)
    initData()
    checkTheme()

    findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).also { toolbar = it }
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewPager).also { viewPager = it }
    findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout).also { tabLayout = it }
    exploreFragment = ExploreFragment()
    flightsFragment = FlightsFragment()
    travelFragment = TravelFragment()
    with(tabLayout) { this?.setupWithViewPager(viewPager) }
    val viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, 0)
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(exploreFragment!!,resources.getString(R.string.home))
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(flightsFragment!!, "Flights")
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(travelFragment!!,resources.getString(R.string.dictionary))
    with(viewPager) {
        this!!.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
    }
    val tabLayout = tabLayout
    tabLayout?.getTabAt(0)?.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_home)
    tabLayout?.getTabAt(1)?.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_flights)
    tabLayout?.getTabAt(2)?.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_dictionary)
    val badgeDrawable: BadgeDrawable = tabLayout?.getTabAt(0)!!.orCreateBadge
    badgeDrawable.isVisible = true
    badgeDrawable.number = 12
    val drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(af.azdreams.myconquer.R.id.drawerLayout)
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    val navView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navView)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.open, 
R.string.close)
    toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.itmFetch ->startActivity(Intent(this,UserProfileActivity::class.java))
            R.id.itmProfile ->startActivity(Intent(this,Profile::class.java))
            R.id.itmLanguage ->showChangeLanguageDialog()
            R.id.itmAppearance ->chooseThemeDialog()
            R.id.itmSignOut ->basicAlert()
            R.id.itmRateAndComments ->{
                val url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus"
                if (url.startsWith("https://") || url.startsWith("http://")) {
                    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
            R.id.itmAbout ->startActivity(Intent(this,About::class.java))
        }
        true
    }
}
private var backPressedTime:Long = 0
private lateinit var backToast: Toast
override fun onBackPressed() {
    backToast = Toast.makeText(this,resources.getString(R.string.press_back_again_to_leave_the_app), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        backToast.cancel()
        super.onBackPressed()
        return
    } else {
        backToast.show()
    }
    backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
private fun showChangeLanguageDialog() {
    val pref = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val listItems = arrayOf("English", "فارسی دری", "پښتو")
    var checkedItem = 0
    when {
        pref.getString("My_Lang", "en").equals("en") -> {
            checkedItem = 0
        }
        pref.getString("My_Lang", "en").equals("fa") -> {
            checkedItem = 1
        }
        pref.getString("My_Lang", "en").equals("ps") -> {
            checkedItem = 2
        }
    }
    mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, checkedItem) { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
        when (i) {
            0 -> {
                setLocale("en")
                startActivity(Intent(this,SplashScreen::class.java))
            }
            1 -> {
                setLocale("fa")
                startActivity(Intent(this,SplashScreen::class.java))
            }
            2 -> {
                setLocale("ps")
                startActivity(Intent(this,SplashScreen::class.java))
            }
        }
        dialogInterface.dismiss()
    }
    val mDialog = mBuilder.create()
    mDialog.show()
}
private fun setLocale(lang: String?) {
    val locale = Locale(lang)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.locale = locale
    baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)
    val editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang)
    editor.apply()
}
private fun loadLocale() {
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val language = prefs.getString("My_Lang", "")
    setLocale(language)
}
private fun basicAlert(){
    val positiveButtonClick = { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
    val negativeButtonClick = { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    with(builder) {
        setMessage(R.string.do_you_want_to_sign_out_from_your_my_conquer_account)
        setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, positiveButtonClick)
        setPositiveButton(R.string.yes) { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            auth.signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this@DashboardActivity, SignInActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }
        setNegativeButton(R.string.no, negativeButtonClick)
        show()
    }
}
private fun initData(){
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    setUserEmail()
}
private fun setUserEmail(){
    getCurrentUserEmail()
}
private fun getCurrentUserEmail():String? {
    return auth.currentUser?.email
}
private fun chooseThemeDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val styles = arrayOf(resources.getString(R.string.light),resources.getString(R.string.dark),resources.getString(
        R.string.system_default))
    val checkedItem = MyPreferences(this).darkMode
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(styles, checkedItem) { dialog, which ->
        when (which) {
            0 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                MyPreferences(this).darkMode = 0
                delegate.applyDayNight()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            1 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                MyPreferences(this).darkMode = 1
                delegate.applyDayNight()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            2 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
                MyPreferences(this).darkMode = 2
                delegate.applyDayNight()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
class MyPreferences(context: Context?) {
    companion object {
        private const val DARK_STATUS = ""
    }
    private val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    var darkMode = preferences.getInt(DARK_STATUS, 0)
    set(value) = preferences.edit().putInt(DARK_STATUS, value).apply()
}
private fun checkTheme() {
    when (MyPreferences(this).darkMode) {
        0 -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            delegate.applyDayNight()
        }
        1 -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            delegate.applyDayNight()
        }
        2 -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
            delegate.applyDayNight()
        }
    }
}
private class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, behavior: Int) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, behavior) {
    private val fragments: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    private val fragmentTitle: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        fragments.add(fragment)
        fragmentTitle.add(title)
    }
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragments.size
    }
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return fragmentTitle[position]
    }
}
private fun getUserData() {
    val scoresRef = Firebase.database.getReference("Users")
    scoresRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)!!
            val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvFirstNameAndLastName)
            val phoneNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPhoneNumber)
            name.text = user.name+" "+user.lastName
            phoneNumber.text = user.phoneNumber
            getUserProfile()
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            finish()
        }
    })
}
private fun getUserProfile() {
    val navigationView = binding.navView
    val header: View = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Users/$uid")
    val localeFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile","")
    storageReference.getFile(localeFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localeFile.absolutePath)
        val picture = header.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.circleImageView)
        picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        finish()
    }
}
private fun onClickListenerSearchUser(){
    binding.btnSearchUsers.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this,SearchUsers::class.java))
    }
}
```

}

the header.xml in layout folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:background="@color/Orange">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/White"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.047"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.213" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFirstNameAndLastName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFirstNameAndLastName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the user.class that is for user profile information :

```
package af.azdreams.myconquer

data class User(var name : String ?= null, var lastName : String ?= null, var educationLevel : String ?= null, var province : String ?= null, var age : String ?= null, var phoneNumber : String ?= null)
```

please help me on this issue.
thank you!

Comment: can you please port the layout where tvFirstNameAndLastName this used

Comment: Yes ofcorse and I added that at the end of my question please check.

Comment: At which particular line of code does that error occur?

Comment: in this line : [name.text = user.name+" "+user.lastName] and when I remove it at the next line which is : [phoneNumber.text = user.phoneNumber] they are both in dashbordactivity.kt

Comment: Clearly, the TextViews are not being found in OnDataChange. You need to investigate why.

Comment: This may not fix your issue, but you should call `setContentView` first, before you try to access any views. Then, when accessing views, use your `binding` instead of `findViewById`